# How to change key for array's objects' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var originalArray = [
      {Name: "IPHONE8s", Id: 4}, 
      {Name: "Iphone 9", Id: 5}, 
      {Name: "IPHONEX", Id: 6}
];
```

how to change it to be something like this

```
var changeArray = [
      {text: "IPHONE8s", value: 4 },
      {text: "Iphone 9", value: 5 },
      {text: "IPHONEX", value: 6 }
]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please remove your comment and replace the new code line to your post. You can doing this, by click on the edit link underneath your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use **Array.map()**

```js
var originalArray = [
      {Name: "IPHONE8s", Id: 4}, 
      {Name: "Iphone 9", Id: 5}, 
      {Name: "IPHONEX", Id: 6}
];

var changeArray = originalArray.map(data => ({text: data.Name, value: data.Id}))

console.log(changeArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` with Object destructuring:

```js
let data = [
  {Name: "IPHONE8s", Id: 4},
  {Name: "Iphone 9", Id: 5},
  {Name: "IPHONEX", Id: 6}
];

let result = data.map(({Name:text, Id:value}) => ({text, value}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**References:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Answer (score 0):

Example code

```
function renameKeys(obj, newKeys) {
  const keyValues = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    const newKey = newKeys[key] || key;
    return { [newKey]: obj[key] };
  });
  return Object.assign({}, ...keyValues);
}
```

And use it like:

```
const obj = { a: "1", b: "2" };
const newKeys = { a: "A", c: "C" };
const renamedObj = renameKeys(obj, newKeys);
console.log(renamedObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the objects by mapping the key value pairs with a new name by using an object for the keys and their new name for replacement.

This proposal preserves other properties.

```js
var array = [{ Name: "IPHONE8s", Id: 4, foo: 'bar' }, { Name: "Iphone 9", Id: 5 }, { Name: "IPHONEX", Id: 6 }],
    replace = { Name: 'text', Id: 'value' },
    result = array.map(o => Object.assign(...Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [replace[k] || k]: v }))
    ));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalArray = [{Name: "IPHONE8s", Id: 4}, {Name: "Iphone 9", Id: 5}, {Name: 
"IPHONEX", Id: 6} ];
let changeArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
  let tmpObj = {}
  tmpObj.text = originalArray[i].Name
  tmpObj.value = '' + originalArray[i].Id
  changeArray.push(tmpObj) 
}
console.log(changeArray)
```